# ponylang - I can't figure out how to convert type

Tags: ponylang

Starting with the [helloworld](http://tutorial.ponylang.org/getting-started/helloworld/), I am trying to learn me some pony by making an app which echoes back to the user what they have typed in. This works, except for the one line where I `_env.out.print(_buffer)`.

```
class MyInput iso is StdinNotify
  var _env: Env
  var _buffer: Array[U8]

  new iso create(env: Env) =>
    _env = env
    _buffer = Array[U8].create()

  fun ref apply(data: Array[U8] iso) =>
    for item in (consume data).values() do
      if item == 0x0A then
        _env.out.print(_buffer)
        _buffer = Array[U8].create()
      end
      _buffer.push(item)
    end
```

The compile errors I get are:

```
argument not a subtype of parameter
        _env.out.print(_buffer)
                       ^
parameter type: ByteSeq val
  be print(data: ByteSeq) =>
           ^
argument type: Array[U8 val] ref
        _env.out.print(_buffer)
```

From reading the source in [github](https://github.com/ponylang/ponyc/blob/0103b02e5a96574eb50214ed313c1b1ff49b6337/packages/builtin/stdstream.pony) I *think* that Array[U8] should qualify as  a ByteSeq, so I guess that it's a problem with the capabilities. I've tried a few things but I can't seem to copy my ref Array into a val Array. The closest I got was `let out: Array[U8] box =  _buffer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to the pony mailing list and more trial and error I've got it to work. (thanks sean allen)

```
actor Main
  new create(env: Env) =>
    env.out.print("welcome to the echo chamber")

    var input = recover iso MyInput.create(env) end
    env.input(consume input)

class MyInput is StdinNotify
  var _env: Env
  var _buffer: Array[U8] iso

  new  create(env: Env) =>
    _env = env
    _buffer = recover iso Array[U8].create() end

  fun ref apply(data: Array[U8] iso) =>
      for item in (consume data).values() do
        if  item == 0x0A then
          let bufferOutIso = _buffer = recover iso Array[U8].create() end
          _env.out.print(consume bufferOutIso)
        else
          _buffer.push(item)
        end
      end
```

so in case any of this needs explaining,

- it turns out that although print asks for a `val` argument, it will take an `iso`, for reasons I don't fully understand
- when using `iso`, you need to understand `recover` blocks and [destructive read](http://tutorial.ponylang.org/capabilities/consume-and-destructive-read/#destructive-read)
- I made a mistake putting iso in the class definition, I only needed to create the instance in a `recover iso` block

Comment: Anything will accept an `iso` because by consuming the `iso` (which is required to pass it as a parameter) you are destroying all of the existing references to the object, thus any guarantees the target type requires (in this case that no one on any thread can write to it) can be satisfied.